# sbt: rerun failed tests one more time

Tags: scala, sbt

Maven has this feature to rerun all failed tests again to see if they fail consistently or not

https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/rerun-failing-tests.html

How can I archive the same with SBT without actually changing the tests?

I know I can use `testOnly` to rerun failed tests manually, but I want this to happen during the `test` phase in one sbt run.

Using `Retries` trait requires changing the source code, which is not desirable.

Comment: seems like sbt has [testQuick](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Testing.html#testQuick). It says `Executes the tests that either failed before, were not run or whose transitive dependencies changed, among those provided as arguments`. I create a dummy test in my local with one doing something like `1 should be(1)` and the other one `1 should be(2)`. Using that command always execute both tests. Same happens if I add more succeeding or failing tests. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: `testOnly` requires that I run sbt a second time, can I have `testOnly` behaviour with `test` ?

Comment: What test framework are you using? I don't think this can be achieved in SBT but maybe scalatest has some helpers for that of you're using Scalatest.

Comment: Scalatest has `Retries`: https://www.scalatest.org/scaladoc/3.2.17/org/scalatest/Retries.html

Answer (score 1):

It's not built-in, but there's a plugin that seems to do what you're looking for: https://github.com/otrebski/sbt-flaky

Alternatively, `scalatest` also has a built-in `trait` designed specifically for flaky tests: https://www.scalatest.org/scaladoc/3.2.17/org/scalatest/Retries.html